# Есть ли какие-то книги по программированнию шахматных программ?

Tags: c++

Есть ли книги по алгоритмам, которые используются в программировании шахматных программ, но кроме книги Корнилова(она у меня уже есть)

Comment: сомневаюсь, слишком узконаправленная тема

Comment: ну хотя бы статьи... Хоть на английском

Comment: ну уж статьи то и самому можно найти

Comment: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page

Comment: 1) перебор + 2) оценка качества фигур и вычисление некоторого веса - вот самый простой шахматный алгоритм

Comment: алгоритмы перебора типа Minimax с AlphaBeta отсечением лишних ветвей дерева поиска мне знакомы, моя цель разобраться в том, как представлять шахматную доску в памяти компьютера